# Cannot insert value NULL into column, but values in error message have nothing to do with my code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a VB.NET program that calls a stored procedure in SQL Server which inserts data into a table. Upon running this code, I get the following error message:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure uspAddSponsor, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 406]
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'intGenderID', table 'dbSQL1.dbo.TGolfers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The problem is that neither `intGenderID` nor `TGolfers` are referenced in the stored procedure.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddSponsor
    --@intGolferID              AS INTEGER OUTPUT
    @strFirstName AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strLastName AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strStreetAddress AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strCity AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strState AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strZip AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strPhoneNumber AS VARCHAR(255),
    @strEmail AS VARCHAR(255)
AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TSponsors (strFirstName, strLastName, strStreetAddress, strCity, strState, strZip, strPhoneNumber, strEmail)
    VALUES (@strFirstName, @strLastName, @strStreetAddress, @strCity, @strState, @strZip, @strPhoneNumber, @strEmail)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

Here is the code used to call the stored procedure:

```
EXECUTE uspAddSponsor 'Joe', 'Johnson', '420 Main St', 'Ashton Park', 'IN', '46225', '5136656969', 'jjohnson@gmail.com'
```

Here's the sticky part. Running the INSERT statement by itself works with no problems. However, executing the stored procedure, which features the exact same `INSERT` statement, causes the error above. I truly have no idea what's going on.

There's no foreign key linking TGolfers and TSponsors. TSponsors doesn't even have an intGenderID column. I have no idea what could be causing this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look for a trigger, maybe with some logic that behaves differently depending on the calling context.

Comment: Did you try execute the stored procedure in SSMS ?

Comment: One possibility is that you have two SPs with the same name but under different schemas. When creating / calling an SP it is good idea to specify the schema e.g. `EXECUTE dbo.uspAddSponsor ...`

Comment: Maybe a synonym is used here? Current database is not set to the one you assume?

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed the problem, although I'm not sure why the error occurred in the first place. I still have the DB script that I had used to create the db and everything in it, so I re-ran the script to reset the database, and the problem went away.